# Django - How to process requests to webservices and what to do when requests fail?

Tags: python, django

I will use Django to provide a service when a payment is done.

Basically I will use Django to wait until I receive a request to a certain URL, for example:

```
http://mydjangowaitforrequestserver.com/callback?key=somekey&param1=some1&param2=some2
```

After I receive q request like this I will have many tasks to do. This tasks will could succeed or fail. If a task fail I have to retry, If for example a task fails more than 10 times I will abort.

A good exemple would be:

1 - Wait for callback request to http://mydjangowaitforrequestserver.com/callback?key=somekey&param1=some1&param2=some2

2 - Call/Request an external webservice to confirm the task. If the call/request fail, I will retry 10 times, after 10 retry fails, I will abort and send email alerting process failed.

3 - Call/Request an external webservice to buy X amount of X. If the call/request fail, I will retry 10 times, after 10 retry fails, I will abort and send email alerting process failed.

..
..

10 - Send email alerting process terminated with success.

In Django how can I deal with this kind of tasks? What I should de aware of?

And more important, Django give me the tools to do something like this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't really have anything out of the box for this. You probably want to look at something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which integrates with django nicely and handles all of the management functionality you need for handling tasks.